# What is the g_editable attribute?

Tags: html

I keep seeing things like `<div ... g_editable="true" ... >`.

I've searched for anything to help me understand its purpose, but all I get back is more markup and nothing explaining it.

Can somebody please explain it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The g_editable="true" attribute is used by Google in their Gmail email composition (and likely other Google products as well). Instead of using a textarea tag they use a source-less iframe and all of the email contents are highlighted, typed in, made bold, adding line breaks etc are all handled by javascript so that it resembles a textarea, but with a lot more functionality.

The g_editable="true" attribute itself is likely to limit the scope that different functions and events have so that you can't just boldify text in your contacts list and that sort of thing. It's probably why they have it in an iframe as well.

Comment: g_editable is defined in the open source closure library that google uses in gmail, google+, and other projects.  The attribute is set by the [goog.editor.Field](http://closure-library.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/closure/goog/editor/field.js) class.

Answer (score 2):

It may just be a custom attribute defined by Google. It could be a hook for their JavaScript and/or CSS.

For best practice though, they should have prefixed it with [`data-`](http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/).

Comment: Fair enough.  Sorry I'm super new to HTML.  Does that mean that I can put in any attribute I want and find it with CSS/JavaScript?

Comment: @ptpaterson Sort of. It is not valid in non HTML5 doctypes. But most browsers won't have an issue.